Error JSON con sweetalert2
Tengo un error a la hora de pasar un json desde php a el plugin sweetalert:
$alerta=[
                "tipo"=>"simple",
                "titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "texto"=>"No has llenado todos los campos que son obligatorios",
                "icono"=>"error"
            ];
            return json_encode($alerta);

En el archivo js que lo recibe hago una llamada fetch:
 fetch(action,config)
                .then(respuesta =>respuesta.json())
                .then(respuesta => {
                    return alertas_ajax(respuesta);
                })

Pues respuesta.json() me dice que el formato json es incorrecto.
El JSON que devuelve return json_encode($alerta); es:
{"tipo":"simple","titulo":"Ocurri\u00f3 un error inesperado","texto":"Las CLAVES no coinciden con el formato solicitado","icono":"error"}

¿Alguna idea para un novato?
Gracias

Añadiendo JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE como segundo parámetro a json_encode funciona:
return json_encode($alerta,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


Esta parece la respuesta correcta, solo agregaría que del lado del servidor tienes que(o no necesariamente pero deberías) definir el encabezado correcto "content-type" para que el cliente sepa que recibirá datos en formato json, así: header('Content-Type: application/json');
